# Behaviour of sprintf in hexadecimal with negative integers

Tags: c++, format, printf

I'm trying to debug an existing code trying to **format a small integer into an hexadecimal 4-char C-string**. But the behaviour is apparently **inconsistent between positive and negative integers**.

Here is the code:

```
char mystring[5];
mystring[4] = 0;

sprintf (mystring, "%04X", (char)(61))
// ---> mystring is "FF3D" [OK]
// ---> return value is 4 (chars written) [OK]
 
sprintf (mystring, "%04X", (char)(-61))
// ---> mystring is "FFFFFFC3" [NOT OK]
// ---> return value is 8 (chars written) [NOT OK]
```

In the second case, I have **8 characters written, despite the `%04X` format**. What is going on? How can I limit to only 4 chars the result?

Comment: char is promoted to integer type. Signed types are filling extra space with oldest bit, so you got `FF` in front. Note that format string `%x` represent `int` type. Try `%04hhX`. https://godbolt.org/z/jf4ao5

Comment: @MarekR `%x` is for `unsigned int`, not `int`. The `char` argument is promoted to `int` (or `unsigned int` on some exotic systems).

Answer (score 2):

The "%04" tells sprintf only the minimum number of digits to use.

If the number needs more, it will get more so the output is not truncated.

Answer (score 2):

That happens because of [integral promotion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion#Integral_promotion) rules. In function calls, `char` is promoted to an `int`. `int` is usually represented as 32 bit two's complement, so a negative value like `-61` becomes `FFFFFFC3`.

Then, the *width* field like in `%04` specifies the *minimum* width. When a value exceeds that, it is printed as-is.

As a workaround, you can use the `hh` [length](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Printf_format_string#Length_field) field, which specifies that the original value was a `char` and should be treated as such.

```
sprintf (mystring, "%04hhX", -61);
```

- should output `00C3`.

> *If i use `sprintf (mystring, "%04hhX", (char)(-61));` as you suggest, I get `00C3` instead of `FFC3`. What is going on?*

A `char` is in practice 1 byte (8 bits). So `-61` is `C3`. The `00` prefix comes from the padding requirement of `04`. To get `FFC3`, use a 16-bit data type (e.g. `short`) for example `"%04hX"`:

```
sprintf (mystring, "%04hX", -61);
```

- should output `FFC3`.

Alternatively you can trim unnecessary bits before formatting, and treat the value as `unsigned int`

```
sprintf (mystring, "%04X", (-61 & 0xFFFF));
```

The [bitwise-and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) operation (`&`) is useful for setting unnecessary bits to 0.

---

Note that I'm mixing `signed` and `unsigned int` in this post. That is intentional and is [OK to do](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43336256/485343). The behavior is implementation-defined, but always works because all modern computers are based on two's complement integer representation. For example, the last example can be "improved" by using an unsigned value: `(-61 & 0xFFFFu)`, but will have absolutely no effect on the end result.

Comment: Does `hh` cause `printf` to ignore most significant 3 bytes?

Comment: yes it does, you can drop casting to char too.

Comment: Technically, `hh` for `%X` expects the input to be an `unsigned char`, not a `char`.

Comment: @rustyx If i use `sprintf (mystring, "%04hhX", (char)(-61));` as you suggest, I get `00C3` instead of `FFC3`. What is going on?

Comment: @Silverspur a `char` is in practice 1 byte (8 bits). So `-61` is `C3`. The `00` prefix comes from your padding requirement of `04`. To get `FFC3`, you need to use a 16-bit data type (e.g. `short`) for example `"%04hX"`

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> "%04X", (char)(61)
> ```

You have used the wrong format specifier. As a result, the behaviour of the program is undefined. On exotic systems, the behaviour may be inadvertently well defined, but probably not what you intended.

`%X` is for `unsigned int`. The `char` argument promotes (on most systems) to `int` for which the format specifier is not allowed. Regardless, format specifiers for `int` and `unsigned int` will treat the input as a multi-byte value. It just so happens that a 4 byte int represents the value -61 as FF'FF'FF'C3.

To ignore the high bytes of the promoted argument, you must use the length specifier in the format. `hh` is for `signed char` and `unsigned char`. Note that there is no numeric format specifier for `char`. Furthermore, there is no hex format for signed numbers. So, you should be using `unsigned char`. Here is a correct example:

```
unsigned char c = -61;
std::sprintf (mystring, "%04hhX", c);
```

And another, using signed decimal:

```
signed char c = -61;
std::sprintf (mystring, "%04hhd", c);
```

> I have 8 characters written, despite the %04X format.

The width does not limit the number of characters. It is minimum width to which the output is padded.

> How can I limit to only 4 chars the result?

Use `std::snprintf` instead:

```
int count = std::snprintf(nullptr,
  sizeof mystring,"%04hhX", c);
assert(count < sizeof mystring);
std::snprintf(mystring,
  sizeof mystring,"%04hhX", c);
```

> when I use your first suggestion with an unsigned char, I get 00C3 instead of FFC3. What is going on?

When -63 is converted to unsigned char, the resulting value is 195. 195 is C3 in hexadecimal.

---

P.S. Consider using `std::format` if possible.

Comment: Same comment as for @rustyx answer: when I use your first suggestion with an `unsigned char`, I get `00C3` instead of `FFC3`. What is going on?